# Installing tex 2020 from the iso: Can't locate TeXLive/TLUtils.pm in @INC (you may need to install the TeXLive::TLUtils module)

Tags: installing, texlive-2020

When I try to install texlive 2020 from the iso 20200406 I found two problems
         1) for some inexplicable reason the first line of `install-tl` is `!/usr/bin/env perl` instead of `#!/usr/bin/env perl`.      Why on earth would that be?
          Since /mnt/iso is read only I had to copy install-tl to my own file system, fix it, and then run the copy.    Maybe that's the source of the problem but I can't imagine it is.
         2) The next problem is the error message:

```
Can't locate TeXLive/TLUtils.pm in @INC (you may need to install the TeXLive::TLUtils module)
```

I can't find anything on the web about this, could somebody please advise?

Comment: same problem...

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I extracted ISO using `7z e` which silently flattened the directory structure. Need to use `7z x` (my answer to myself is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/600868/115598).