# install-tl from iso in non-root env

Tags: texlive, installing

For doing some reproducible build scripts involving TexLive, I'm trying to install TexLive from the ISO file (outdated 2020 version also for delaying updating the rest of the setup for now):

```
mkdir -p source/texmfrepo build/texlive-basic
wget -P source https://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tug/historic/systems/texlive/2020/texlive2020-20200406.iso
7z e source/texlive2020-20200406.iso -aoa -osource/texmfrepo || true
echo selected_scheme scheme-basic > build/texlive.profile
echo TEXDIR $PWD/build/texlive-basic >> build/texlive.profile
echo TEXMFLOCAL $PWD/build/texlive-basic/texmf-local >> build/texlive.profile
echo TEXMFSYSVAR $PWD/build/texlive-basic/texmf-var >> build/texlive.profile
echo TEXMFSYSCONFIG $PWD/build/texlive-basic/texmf-config >> build/texlive.profile
TEXLIVE_INSTALL_NO_RESUME=1 ./source/texmfrepo/install-tl --repository source/texmfrepo --profile build/texlive.profile
```

`install-tl` fails with: `/home/runner/work/_temp/12ccd0a3-5984-4e93-ae83-7bc097231026.sh: line 9: ./source/texmfrepo/install-tl: Permission denied Error: Process completed with exit code 126.`

I'm running this code as GitHub workflow([`.github/workflows/installtl.yml`](https://github.com/vadimkantorov/installtltest/blob/master/.github/workflows/installtl.yml), [full log](https://github.com/busytex/busytex/runs/2800037874?check_suite_focus=true)).

How do I `install-tl` properly? Thanks!

Comment: I have no clue as to what exactly you are doing here, but in any case you need to tell the installer to install stuff in a location where you have the rights to. But I think the error indicate something completely different. `install-tl` is a perl program, have you tried `perl ./source/texmfrepo/install-tl`, seems to me that you haven't set the execution bit, and thus `./program` is not allowed to run

Comment: I guess I checked `chmod +x source/texmfrepo/install-tl` wrongly for the first time. Thanks for the tip! Once I fix it, I get the error `Can't locate TeXLive/TLUtils.pm in @INC (you may need to install the TeXLive::TLUtils module)`. Same problem as in  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544805/installing-tex-2020-from-the-iso-cant-locate-texlive-tlutils-pm-in-inc-you-m

Comment: And same problem with `TeXLive/TLUtils.pm` even with TexLive 2021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case solved:

1. need to use `chmod +x source/texmfrepo/install-tl`, as advised by @daleif
2. more importantly, should not use `7z e`, it flattens and destroys the directory structure, should use `7z x`, then installation completes!